# Where's the windows 10 driver for the Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: windows, driver

I have a brand new Raspberry Pi Pico. And when I connect it to my Windows 10 PC i get a new device with missing drivers.

[image]

Guess what: pressing "Update Driver..." is not very helpfull here.

I makes no difference if I press the BOOTSEL button or not. Changing USB ports doesn't help either.

So I've been googling for answers, but found nothing.

Comment: Have you looked through the Pico documentation on-line?

Comment: there's nothing about this "RP2 boot" driver in the docs, and it's very scarce in all other online places too.  I currently have the same problem, it appears to me as this "RP2 boot" device, and I have no hidden com port or anything, and nothing appears in explorer, so I basically cannot program my PICO, nor can I find any info on how to make it so I can. Tons of blogs and videos on how to write your first sketch, but no one mentions this missing driver thing.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well. The pico drive appeared after all, in spite of this error.
So there is no real windowd driver needed.
I still find this very annoying and confusing. But the problem is solved.

Comment: what is annoying and confusing about something that works?

Comment: @Bravo mostly the fact that there is zero indication that it works. Just a com port in the hidden "Ports (COM & LPT)" section of device manager.

Comment: I generally find the "devices by connection" view in device manager far more informative than the "devices by type" view.